# React native project doesn't run iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I've started React-Native programing recently. When I want to create a new project based on a guidence of "https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup"  and want to run  in xcode 12.5 this error is shown:

> bash: Progects/Trading: No such file or directory
>
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg1vF.png)

I' ll be thankfull of guiding me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed pods. If you already installed then delete the pods folder and podfile.lock inside the ios.

Run this command on your terminal:

```
cd ios && pod install && cd ..
```

Open your ios folder through finder and open .xcworkspace file and run from their